# Windows 8 upgrade assistant weird behaviour

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

Please excuse me for the header of the question because I can't describe the problem in a few words.

The problem is that I'm using windows 8 upgrade assistant on windows 7.

Everything works fine until a screen comes up that checks my system and wants me to confirm that I will add my languages after I install windows 8.

The problem here is that the upgrade advisor have a small window to display the HTML file that have a confirm button while the HTML file opens in the browser not in the advisor window, so the button does nothing.

[image]

I have tried to change default browser to IE with no success, the HTML file still opens in IE not the advisor window.

I have searched everywhere but seems I'm the only one getting this.

Comment: Remove the language packs ahead of time.  This way it won't ask you to confirm you will install your language packs.  I found numerous results of this exact problem, when I did a good search, [strange](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/youll-have-to-add-your-languages-back-in-windows-8/5bda4edf-e27c-46b4-8adb-7263d374f121?page=1)

Comment: I will try this now and feed you back. Thank you for the help

Comment: [google search is your friend](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/youll-have-to-add-your-languages-back-in-windows-8/667876b0-81ea-4774-821e-ac9aa3bc96c9)

Comment: Removing the language pack worked fine. 
By the way, I have searched a lot but couldn't reach anything.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Those were just 2 of the search results I found, I searched for exactly the message in the screenshot, there are others.